# Why can't I create active records that count for something in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Why after I create records is the count zero ?

```
require 'spec_helper'
...
describe "keep admin" do

  its "Can't delete the only admin" do
    user1 = User.create(username: 'user1', password: 'abc123', admin: true)
    user2 = User.create(username: 'user2', password: 'def456', admin: true)
    user3 = User.create(username: 'user3', password: 'ghi798', admin: true)
    #User.delete_me(user1) currently commented out to be sure.
    #User.delete_me(user2)
    #User.delete_me(user3)
    expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 3
  end

end

  1) keep admin Can't delete the only admin should eq 3
     Failure/Error: expect(User.where(admin: true).count).to eq 3

       expected: 3
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.41264 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure

$ RAILS_ENV=test rails c
User
Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.17)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > User
 => User(id: integer, username: string, pwd_hashed: string, salt: string,  
created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean)
```

I can create users ok when using the app itself.
I tried `create` and `create!`.  Why is the count always zero ?

Edit - full User model -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'digest/sha1'
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :admin

  validates_presence_of     :username
  validates_uniqueness_of   :username
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validate :password_non_blank

  def self.delete_me(user)
    how_many_admins = User.where(admin: true).count
    if how_many_admins > 1 
      puts "delete ok!"
      user.delete
    else
      puts "delete not ok!"
    end 
  end 

  def self.authenticate(name, password)
    user = self.find_by_username(name)
    if user
      expected_password = encrypted_password(password, user.salt)
      if user.pwd_hashed != expected_password
        user = nil 
      end 
    end 
    user
  end 
  def password
    @password
  end 

  def password=(pwd)
    @password = pwd 
    return if pwd.blank?
    create_new_salt
    self.pwd_hashed = User.encrypted_password(self.password, self.salt)
  end 

  def is_admin
    admin ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  end 

private
  def password_non_blank
    errors.add(:password, "Missing password") if pwd_hashed.blank?
  end 

  def create_new_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end 

  def self.encrypted_password(password, salt)
    string_to_hash = password + "wibble" + salt
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string_to_hash)
  end 

end
```

Comment: What is your user table setup as? It could be that the create is never happening

Comment: Added that info from rails console.

Comment: `expected: 1 got: 0` is very suspicious. It should be expecting 3. Is this representative of your actual code?  Also, do you have code that sweeps your DB between tests?

Comment: Do you have any validations that might also be causing the records to be uncreated (I notice you have a salt value in the schema but not initialization).

Comment: Corrected, it was 3 (I had been playing around with 1 too), i.e. I am expected 3 getting 0

Comment: Try using `create!` instead of `create`.

Comment: When you say you "tried `create!`", did you get the exact same failure (i.e. 0 vs. 3)?

Comment: Can you try with 1 user and add this before your `count` expectation.  `user1.valid?` `expect(user1.errors).to_be empty`

Comment: In your User model I see the column as `pwd_hashed` not `password`.

Answer (score 0):

Your admin attribute isn't being persisted to the database (because of the call to `attr_accessor`), so counting users where `admin` is true will always return 0.

It also looks like your password confirmation should fail, since you're not actually providing a confirmation.